Match user input to associated dictionary text
I am trying to create a Part Number generator for an existing list of products.
I would like the user to input the description, series etc. in the userform and from that a new (non-duplicated) part number to be generated.
The part number follows this format: XXXyyy-WWW
Where XXX is a three letter abbreviation for the part, yyy is series number (three numbers) and WWW is a department number reference.
For Example: BRC569-896 where BRC refers to a bracket with the series number 569 (Next Available Series Number in the BRC product range) and 896 is the department reference/origin.
I have gone through the existing part numbers to create a dictionary of the abbreviations used. An example of this is below:
ASM - Assembly
BRC - Bracket
CAB - Cable
FLG - Flange
FOO - Foot Pad
GLU - Glue/Adhesive
SCR - Screw

The abbreviations do not follow a particular pattern like using the first three letters etc. I thought creating a dictionary of the abbreviations used in the old list would allow the VBA to pick up the word and produce the abbreviation to create the part number.
For example: "Cable" is typed in the description and "CAB" is picked up as the beginning of the new part number.
How do I create this?
Is there an alternative method?

Assuming the mapping table is stored on worksheet. The script loads the mapping table into a Dict object.
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, c As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String, aTxt
    Dim arrData
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    arrData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        aTxt = Split(arrData(i, 1), " - ")
        sKey = aTxt(1)
        If Not objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            objDic(sKey) = aTxt(0)
        End If
    Next i
    ' Testing code
    For Each c In Range("C2:C3") ' Read description from cell
        sKey = c.Value
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            MsgBox sKey & "'s abbreviation is " & objDic(sKey)
        Else
            MsgBox sKey & " doesn't exists"
        End If
    Next
End Sub


